# Calling an ASPX file in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

I'm trying to get an iFrame working by embedding an ASPX file from a different site on my client's Wordpress, and it's been giving me a headache. I have searched and tested every method.

I'm trying to embed this ASPX:
http://www.salonvision.com/TheRetreat/AppointmentSearchFBTab.aspx?backcolor=FFFFFF

Into this wordpress site:
https://theretreatdurham.com/book-online/

Below is the code my client gave me which does not work, just opens up blank for me. And I have tried every method I could find online. Any help would be so much appreciated.

```html
<br class=“Apple-interchange-newline”> <iframe src=“http://www.salonvision.com/TheRetreat/AppointmentSearchFBTab.aspx?backcolor=FFFFFF” scrolling=“no” width=“600px” height=“1400px” frameborder=“0”> </iframe>
```

I changed it to this code which works partially:

```html
<iframe  runat="server" src="http://www.salonvision.com/TheRetreat/AppointmentSearchFBTab.aspx?backcolor=FFFFFF" frameborder=“0” scrolling=“no” style="width: 840px; height: 600px; frameborder: 0;"></iframe>
```

I assume the runat="server" or the iFrame styling changed it to work for me better, but it's only working in a few browsers. I've posted an image below that shows all the browsers tested. I need to find a code that has more viability than that :P

[Image of Multiple Browser Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc9uE.png)

Comment: Hi Skyler, can you share the methods you have tried that didn't work? [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.salonvision.com/TheRetreat/AppointmentSearchFBTab.aspx?backcolor=FFFFFF" scrolling=“no” width=“600px” height=“1400px” frameborder=“0”></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that method too an sort of worked, it didn't show some elements for me for some reason.
I finally found some code that worked so I'll share it hoping it helps someone.